# Check if exist nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionaries like this:

```
my_nested_dictionary= {'key5': 'value5',
                       'key6': {'inner_key6_1': 'inner_value6_1'},
                       'key7': 'value7'}

empty_dict = {}
```

If I want to update `empty_dict` with an inner dict from `my_nested_dictionary`, I can do that with this code:

```
for key, value in my_nested_dictionary.iteritems():
    if key=='key6':
        empty_dictionary.update(value)
```

However, is there any universal way to do this without using an 'if condition' hardcoded for exactly one key? If I had more nested dictionaries as a value of more keys in `my_nested_dictionary`, is there a way to update `empty_dictionary` with all of them at once?

Comment: `empty_dict.update(my_nested_dictionary['key6'])`?

Comment: You would have to write a recursive function.  That is, some function `log_dicts(target_dict, log_dict)`.  Then go through `k, v in target_dict.items` and whenever `isinstance(v, dict)` you can call `log_dicts(target_dict, log_dict)`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe That's pretty much the same I already have, just a shorter code. Thank you

Comment: @PatrickHaugh That's it, thank you vary much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need to update an existing dictionary and just want a dictionary containing only nested dictionaries, you can do this instead:

```
only_nested = {k: v for k, v in my_nested_dictionary.items() if isinstance(v, dict)}
```

For example, given this code:

```
my_nested_dictionary = {'key5': 'value5',
                    'key6': {'inner_key6_1': 'inner_value6_1'},
                    'key7': 'value7',
                    'key8': {'inner_key8_1': 'inner_value8_1'}}

only_nested = {k: v for k, v in my_nested_dictionary.items() if isinstance(v, dict)}
print(only_nested)
```

We get this output:

```
{'key6': {'inner_key6_1': 'inner_value6_1'}, 'key8': {'inner_key8_1': 'inner_value8_1'}}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check a nested dictionary;

```
for key, value in my_nested_dictionary.iteritems():
    if isinstance(value, dict):
        empty_dictionary.update(value)
```

Comment: `my_nested_dictionary.items()`, not `iteritems()` (at least for Python 3)

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to get just get the keys in one statement without using a `if`, you can do it like (Python 3):

```
output = list(filter(lambda key: isinstance(my_nested_dictionary[key], dict), my_nested_dictionary.keys()))
```

output will be like ['key 7'].

From there, you can look it up the vales from the original dictionary as you like. This way you don't have to multiple copies of the same objects.